# Dangers of an explicit conversion operator with a 2nd implicit one in the same class

Tags: c++, c++11

I find myself in a situation where I'm tempted to put two conversion operators in a single class.  Normally I would avoid this like the plague.  But with C++ 11 and explicit conversion operators, it seems what I want to achieve is both reasonable and safe.  However I need a sanity check.

Consider the following class ("Distance") meant to tie together a distance value with its unit of measurement.

```
enum class Unit { None = 0, Meter = 1, Foot = 2, }; // None means INVALID

class Distance
{
    Unit   m_unit;
    double m_value;

public:
    Distance() : m_unit(Unit::None), m_value(0.f) {}  // construct invalid
    Distance(Unit u, double, v) : m_unit(u), m_value(v) {}

    Unit   unit() const  { return m_unit; }

    // Two functions that I would like to make into cast operators:

    double value() const { return m_value; }
    bool valid() const { return Unit::None != m_unit; }

    // Cast operators I would LIKE to add and use.  Implicitly cast to
    // double but in "if()" scenarios, cast to bool to check validity

              operator double() const { return m_value; }
     explicit operator bool()         { return valid(); }
};
```

Since a Distance object is meant to be treated as if it were a double value (most of the time), I considered adding the implicit double cast (above).  But in certain contexts, a Distance can be considered "invalid", represented by a unit value of Unit::None. In that case I really like the idea of adding the explicit boolean cast.

The end goal is to be able replace code that currently reads like this:

```
void doSomething(bool b)   {}
void doSomething(double d) {}

void DumpDistance(const Distance& dist)
{
    if (dist.valid())
        std::cout << dist.value() << std::endl;

    doSomething(dist.valid());  // properly calls bool version  
    doSomething(dist.value());  // properly called double version
}
```

into this:

```
void DumpDistance(const Distance& dist)
{
    if (dist)                           // treated as bool (good)
        std::cout << dist << std::endl; // treated as double (good)

    doSomething(dist);                  // calls double overload (good)
}
```

In my testing, it seems the explicit bool operator does the trick.  But I'm not sure.  It looks like the desired overloads are being called.  But I have a built-in aversion to casting operators burned into me in dark old days of the 1990s.

So my question:

***Is this really is as safe as it seems?***  Is there some obvious case I'm missing in which the compiler would complain about an ambiguous conversion  or even worse, silently calls one operator when I wanted another?

(To be clear: I'm not asking about the necessity of this nor about its readability.  Only about the dangers of compile-time ambiguities or conversions I don't want to happen. I need to solidify the concept of explicit conversion operators in my head. )

Comment: Why do you have an implicit `operator double()`? That seems to be the crux of the issue.  That seems incredibly dangerous considering the mixed units involved.

Comment: It is deliberate.  The intent is to cut down on code verbosity.  The user interface that displays these things shows both the numerical value of the object as well as its units.  But when actually formatting that numerical value, while I can always call 'value()', I don't want to have to.  The entire point of this excercise is to safely avoid having to call the 'value()' and 'valid()' member functions if it is safe.  My testing appears to show that it *is* safe but I want to be sure

Comment: Shouldn't `operator bool()` be `operator bool() const`?

Comment: Oops, yes it should, thanks

Comment: I believe it is "as safe as it seems".  Personally -- my opinion -- I don't like the pattern because at the call site, it is relying on "helpful" conversions that (to me) seem too much like magic.  I'd categorize this technique as "too clever by half".  I have used it myself in the past, before I realized I didn't like it.  The `operator bool()` explicit conversion is okay to keep; it's an idiom that is used in the standard C++ library.  My 2¢.

Comment: Yeah, similar concern here.  This is partly an experiment in making my code read better.  If it proves just a bit too "cutesy" I'll change it back.  Just want to avoid the really dumb stuff.